# ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name

Tags: c++, xcode

I get the warning below in my XCode project:

```
In file included from <built-in>:326:
<command line>:8:17: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name [-Wc99-extensions]
#define AgentIPC.mm 1
                ^
<command line>:9:26: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name [-Wc99-extensions]
#define AgentNotification.h 1
```

I do not have any defines like "#define AgentIPC.mm 1" and the compile also says that it originates from some bult-in source?!

Does anyone have a clue what is wrong?

Secondly, how do I disable ISO C99 extension warnings in XCode?

Comment: So you don't have `#define __FILE__ 1` anywhere?

Comment: ... having said that, the error would, instead, be "Reserved identifiers, macros and functions in the standard library shall not be defined, redefined or undefined."

Comment: No I don't. I have the usual:
#ifndef AgentIPC_h
#define AgentIPC_h

Comment: @VolAnd: The OP says "I do not have any defines like `#define AgentIPC.mm 1`" .  OP: You will have to find where those #defines are coming from.  Looks like some sort of translator is generating them.  Do you have something called AgentIPC?

Comment: Yes, I have a file called AgentIPC.mm and a file called AgentIPC.h.